# How do I create a search bar for my firebase object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, searchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I have a firebase database and I want to create a search bar that will filter results from the database objects.
But I do not know how to go about it.

I have looked everywhere to find a good example but none of those I find are related to firebase.
otherwise is there an alternative way I can do this?

structure of the real-time database on firebase
[image]

any help and suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is not really good for searching. The firebase team recommends using a third party solution like algolia.
However if you don't want to go through that you can just retrieve all the data in the  collection or path you want to search, and add searching logic in your client